# AngularJS ui-router state not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I cant access pages when I use this state name item.info:( But when I make state name like itemInfo(not item.info) it all works fine. How can It be fixed and what`s the problem?
UPD: No error showing. Only url change without any action.
Not working:

```
.state('item', {
    url: '/items',
    template: '<items></items>',
}).state('item.info', {
    url: '/:itemId',
    template: '<item-info></item-info>',
    params: {
        itemId: null
    }
})
```

Working:

```
.state('item', {
  url: '/items',
  template: '<items></items>',
}).state('itemInfo', {
  url: '/item/:itemId',
  template: '<item-info></item-info>',
  params: {
    itemId: null
  }
})
```

Comment: it's probably not working because `/:itemId` matches `/items`. Have you tried changing the order?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I tried this  `.state('contacts', {
                url: '/contacts',
            })
            .state('contacts.list', {
                url: '/list',
                template: '<h1>test</h1>'
            })` 
But it didnt work out also which is strange because its from basic angular tutorial

Comment: it might be a problem with your URLs, if you define both `/:itemId` and `/items` the latter might not be matched because the router always picks the first one - I don't know about AngularJS router but in ExpressJS for example this would be the problem

Comment: I tried the thing you said but it didnt work out also

Comment: maybe try to put your code in a fiddle and add it to the question, it's rather hard to tell the problem from just this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .state('item', {
    url: '/items',
    template: '<items></items>',
 })

 .state('item.info', {
    url: '^/:itemId',
    template: '<item-info></item-info>',
    params: {
      itemId: null
 }
})
```

source: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: There is no error.The only thing that changes itself is url. It`s like state doesnt see template or what idk